# Outlook 2007 Profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

List current PST files and locations for PST files from a batch/script file. I want to log the pst file locations to a text file for PC migration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The list of file and file locations can be found by going to Tools -> Account Settings. There is a list of files and file locations that you are looking for. There is even an open file location button so you don't have to go find them in the windows explorer.

If you need any help, let me know with a comment.

-Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to open Control Panel and use the search box to look for Mail.  Open Mail (32-bit) and go press on Data Files.

On the Data Files tab you can highlight a .pst and press on the Open File Location button to see where it is in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PSTimporter` from RedGate to search for all PST files on your network
http://www.red-gate.com/products/PST_Importer/index.htm